# Bounty by Community?

Tags: discussion, bounty, community-user

[A bounty by community](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397972/19341)?

[image]
How does this work?
Was the user deleted while the bounty was active?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as you suggest; this comes up quite regularly, it seems.

Relevant Meta.StackOverflow threads are [#139533](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139533) and those linked to that one.

Comment: +1 thanks, but strange...

Comment: The list of Community's [favorite questions](http://stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=favorites) shows clear favoritism of SharePoint. Is Community on Microsoft's payroll?

Comment: @user79365, FYI: [What can cause the Community user to have favorite questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175992/178818)