# How do Community bounties work?

Tags: support, bounty, community-user

I recently answered a question with a bounty offered by "[Community](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)".  How are such bounties awarded?  Who decides which response gets the bounty?

Comment: Related post on this meta: [Bounty by Community?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9788) On [meta.se]: [How Does the Community User Set Bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139533) In short, this means that the user who originally offered the bounty have deleted their account.

Comment: Regarding the question which answer gets the bounty, I suppose that the standard rules for awarding bounties when none of the answers is selected are in place also here. See the [FAQ about bounties](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info), mainly [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) (the part "What is automatic awarding?".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in some older posts, the fact that the bounty is owned by the [Community user](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-user/info) means that the user who originally offered the bounty have deleted their account. See: [Bounty by Community?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9788) and [How Does the Community User Set Bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139533)

You can find similar past bounties in the [bounties tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties) of the Community user profile's page. If you look at timeline or revision history of some of those question, you can still see who offered the bounty originally - the user is shown in the usual way for deleted accounts, so you'll see something like "user123456".

You have also asked which answer gets the bounty. There are rules how the bounties are handled if the user does not select any answer. As far as I can tell, those rules are applied also when the user in question no longer exists. 
[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) The details can be found in the FAQ post [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/16067/85)) - see the section: "What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?"

Comment: I wasn't sure whether this question should be closed as a duplicate or whether the additional question makes it different from the older question. I have decided to post my comments as an answer - if the two questions are considered close enough to each other, one of them still can be closed as a duplicate.